# How to cast managementobjectcollection to IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IPropertyData>>?

Tags: c#

How to cast managementobjectcollection to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IPropertyData>>` where propertydata is name and value alone?

```
interface IPropertyData
{

     string Name { get; }
     object Value { get; }
}

class ManagementObjectInfo : IManagementInfo
{


    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IPropertyData>> Get(string query)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        return  searcher.Get()  ;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to just cast the reference, but you could use LINQ fairly easily:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IPropertyData>> Get(string query)
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    var results = searcher.Get();
    return results.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>()
        .Select(item => item.Cast<PropertyData>()
                            .Select(x => (IPropertyData)
                                         new PropertyDataImpl(x.Name, x.Value));
}
```

(Where `PropertyDataImpl` is a simple implementation of your `IPropertyData` interface.)

One downside of this: it doesn't perform any disposal. You may well want to materialize the results to a list or something, so that you can dispose of everything as you go.